# Modify kmeans alghoritm for 1d array where order matters

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I want to find groups in one dimensional array where order/position matters. I tried to use numpys kmeans2 but it works only when i have numbers in increasing order. 
I have to maximize average difference between neigbour sub-arrays

For example: if I have array `[1,2,2,8,9,0,0,0,1,1,1]` and i want to get 4 groups the result should be something like `[1,2,2], [8,9], [0,0,0], [1,1,1]`

Is there a way to do it in better then O(n^k)

answer: I ended up with modiied dendrogram, where I merge neigbors only.

Comment: Could you post the relevant snippet of your code, so we can see what you've tried? If you expect a theoretical answer regarding the complexity I would suggest to ask it here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means is about minimizing the least squares. Among it's largest drawbacks (there are many) is that you need to know k. Why do you want to inherit this drawback?

Instead of hacking k-means into not ignoring the order, why don't you instead look at **time series segmentation** and **change detection** approaches that are much more appropriate for this problem?

E.g. split your time series if `abs(x[i] - x[-1]) > stddev` where `stddev` is the standard deviation of your data set. Or the standard deviation of the last 10 samples (in above series, the standard deviation is about 3, so it would split as `[1,2,2], [8,9], [0,0,0,1,1,1]` because the change 0 to 1 is not significant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I was trying to use k-means because I have to be able to set number of group results. My goal is to find best k groups.

Comment: Then just perform k-1 splits, at the points with the largest change!

Comment: But if i have [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7] split should be between 3 and 4.

Comment: Why? unless you start to spell out a perinciple you will never end up with a working solution. In my opinion. that list should never be split between 3 and 4, but the change points are after 1 and before 7.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention for previous example if my K==2. I was thinking for this problem more like maximizing average difference between neigbour sub-arrays

Comment: You really need to get your needs formalized.